# How to change a array of rows in a text file without disturbing the format of the file

Tags: awk, sed

I have an input file, POSCAR, of a DFT code (VASP) as below:

```
System
1.00000000000000
**5.2916193007999999    0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000    5.2916193007999999    0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000    0.0000000000000000   20.0097122192000008**

       Ta   N
         2     4
    Direct
      0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
      0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
      0.1430930929177486  0.6430931269177513  0.5336780085877783
      0.8569068730822487  0.3569069180822488  0.5336780085877783
      0.6430931269177513  0.8569068730822487  0.4663219914122216
      0.3569069180822488  0.1430930929177486  0.4663219914122216
```

I want to deform, or I would say, I want to change some of the parameters with a particular % say 0.5%, (those are in bold).
We can name the arrey of bold parameters as:

```
a11 a12 a13
a21 a22 a23
a31 a32 a33
```

Depending on case by case, I need to modify a11 to a33 (sometimes it may be only a11 or a11 to a13 or all a's) by +0.5% deformation and -0.5% deformation.

I need a shell (bash) script in my job file in such a way that it generates the required deformed data file.

The final data should be in two directories minus (it will have a-a*0.005) and plus ((it will have a+a*0.005).

The final data should be like these:

In plus (mkdir plus) directory, POSCAR file should be this one:

```
System
   1.00000000000000     
     5.3180773973039998995    1.0050000000000000000    1.4925000000000000000
     1.0050000000000000000    5.3180773973039998995    0.2010000000000000000
     1.4925000000000000000    0.2010000000000000000   10.0500000000000000000
   Ta   N
     2     4
Direct
  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
  0.1430930929177486  0.6430931269177513  0.5336780085877783
  0.8569068730822487  0.3569069180822488  0.5336780085877783
  0.6430931269177513  0.8569068730822487  0.4663219914122216
  0.3569069180822488  0.1430930929177486  0.4663219914122216
```

In minus (mkdir minus) directory, POSCAR file should be this one:

```
System
   1.00000000000000     
     5.2651612042959999005    0.9950000000000000000    1.4925000000000000000
     0.9950000000000000000    5.2651612042959999005    0.1990000000000000000
     1.4925000000000000000    0.1990000000000000000   9.9500000000000000000
   Ta   N 
     2     4
Direct
  0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
  0.1430930929177486  0.6430931269177513  0.5336780085877783
  0.8569068730822487  0.3569069180822488  0.5336780085877783
  0.6430931269177513  0.8569068730822487  0.4663219914122216
  0.3569069180822488  0.1430930929177486  0.4663219914122216
```

The important thing is, there will be no change in all the rows appearing below direct.

I am trying to use as below

```
#!/bin/bash
DEFORM=0.005
A11=$(cat POSCAR | head -n 3 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')
A12=$(cat POSCAR | head -n 3 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')
A13=$(cat POSCAR | head -n 3 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}')
A21=$(cat POSCAR | head -n 4 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')
A22=$(cat POSCAR | head -n 4 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')
A23=$(cat POSCAR | head -n 4 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}')
A31=$(cat POSCAR | head -n 5 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')
A32=$(cat POSCAR | head -n 5 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')
A33=$(cat POSCAR | head -n 5 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $3}')
PA11=$(echo "$A11" "$DEFORM" | awk '{printf "%.16f\n",  $1+$1*$2}')
sed -i "s/$A11/$PA11/g" POSCAR
```

but this seems a tough process. I am looking for a simple script.

Comment: If you can think of some way to say "I want to deform the lattice parameters" in laymans terms, describe what that means, and tell us which parts of the input need to be changed in what ways, then we can probably help you.

Comment: Dear Sir, I have updated that statement.

Comment: I THINK when you're saying "directory" above you actually mean "file".

Comment: Dear Sir, you have pointed out the error, I have updated the question. Anyway, it does not matter whether it is a file or a file in those directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you;re trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 {
    plus  = FILENAME "_plus"
    minus = FILENAME "_minus"
}
(3 <= NR) && (NR <= 5) {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%0.16f%s", $i * 1.005, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS) > plus
        printf "%0.16f%s", $i * 0.095, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS) > minus
    }
    next
}
{
    print > plus
    print > minus
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
```

```
$ head -100 file_*
==> file_minus <==
System
1.00000000000000
0.5027038335760000 0.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000 0.5027038335760000 0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000 1.9009226608240002

       Ta   N
         2     4
    Direct
      0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
      0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
      0.1430930929177486  0.6430931269177513  0.5336780085877783
      0.8569068730822487  0.3569069180822488  0.5336780085877783
      0.6430931269177513  0.8569068730822487  0.4663219914122216
      0.3569069180822488  0.1430930929177486  0.4663219914122216

==> file_plus <==
System
1.00000000000000
5.3180773973039992 0.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000 5.3180773973039992 0.0000000000000000
0.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000 20.1097607802959999

       Ta   N
         2     4
    Direct
      0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
      0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
      0.1430930929177486  0.6430931269177513  0.5336780085877783
      0.8569068730822487  0.3569069180822488  0.5336780085877783
      0.6430931269177513  0.8569068730822487  0.4663219914122216
      0.3569069180822488  0.1430930929177486  0.4663219914122216
```

Comment: Actually, the plus and minus are the name of directory (to be created) and in the plus directory we should have POSCAR which is file_plus here and in minus directory we will have POSCAR that is file_minus here. NOTE; name of the file in both directories will be POSCAR only.

Comment: OK then change `plus  = FILENAME "_plus"` to `plus = "plus/" FILENAME` but [you said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68870853/how-to-change-a-array-of-rows-in-a-text-file-without-disturbing-the-format-of-th/68874615?noredirect=1#comment121721580_68870853) it didn't matter if the output was to files or files in directories.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this fileformat, so you have to check that part yourself .

As far as awk, create a script (poscar.awk):

```
BEGIN{ DEFORM=0.005 }
NR>=3 && NR<=5{ 
  $1=$1-DEFORM 
  $2=$2-DEFORM 
  $3=$3-DEFORM 
  printf "         %.16f %.16f %.16f\n", $1, $2, $3   # This prints lines 3-5
}
!(NR>=3 && NR<=5)                                     # This prints all other lines
```

Then you can to: `awk -f poscar.awk inputfile` which will result in:

```
System
       1.00000000000000
         5.2866193008000000 0.9950000000000000 1.4950000000000001
         3.9950000000000001 5.2866193008000000 0.1950000000000000
         2.9950000000000001 0.2950000000000000 9.9949999999999992
       Ta   N
         2     4
    Direct
      0.0000000000000000  0.0000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
      0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000  0.5000000000000000
      0.1430930929177486  0.6430931269177513  0.5336780085877783
      0.8569068730822487  0.3569069180822488  0.5336780085877783
      0.6430931269177513  0.8569068730822487  0.4663219914122216
      0.3569069180822488  0.1430930929177486  0.4663219914122216
```